# What's right way to talk about garlands?

Tags: articles, irregular-plurals, christmas

'Tis the season, and garlands are cropping up in discussions. As you notice in that sentence, I pluralized the word "garland". If I were referring to a single instance, such as one strand hung on a wall, I would use an article: "you should raise the corner of **that** garland so it hangs evenly".

This aligns with some online uses, like [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garland) which has sentences like "Garlands appear in numerous poems" and "A garland is a decorative braid, knot or wreath of flowers, leaves, or other material". However, most Google references use the singular form without an article to refer to garlands in the abstract. Googling "hang garlands" will provide multiple articles with titles like

- "15 Christmas Decoration Hanging Hacks - How to Hang Garland"
- "Tips for How to Hang Garland, Wreaths and Stockings"

Is this another way to pluralize garland? Is this a regional thing?

Comment: Article titles are, like newspaper headlines, 'allowed' to break the usual grammatical rules.  I wouldn't draw any conclusions about, well, not about much in the way of grammar, from a sample of article titles.

Comment: The noncount *garland* looks like home decorating jargon to me. Sort of like the [singular *pant*](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/11/pants.html) (*that's a fine pant!*) in fashion design jargon.